# How to remove/ reset npm proxy

Tags: proxy, node.js

I`m new to nodejs and npm,  my terminal shows me one error when I try to install anything with npm, 
here is a screenshot 
[image]

I remember that I played with proxy configuration like this :

```
npm config set proxy http://localhost:8080/
npm config set https-proxy http://localhost:8080/
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

and that was to solve another issue with npm.
here is the previous error
[image]

please help..
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was a connection problem.

I remember that I played with proxy configuration by mistake like this :

```
   npm config set proxy http://localhost:8080/
   npm config set https-proxy http://localhost:8080/
   npm config set strict-ssl false
```

which made npm client attempts to hit localhost:8080 to pull the module rather than the correct internet endpoint.

so after couple of days of frustration i visited this link

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config

then ran

```
npm config edit
```

which opened a file inside that file i removed those three lines i added above , then everything worked fine.

Note: you might need to reboot as mentioned in  王子1986's comment.

Comment: + I have to reboot .

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer. Removing the proxy with: npm remove proxy or npm remove https_proxy _did not work. Neither did clearing or cleaning the cache!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the **delete** part of the question, check the [npm config delete docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-config#delete):

> `npm config delete key [key ...]`
>
> Deletes the specified keys from all configuration files.

```
## e.g. delete the proxy configs:
npm config delete proxy https-proxy strict-ssl
```

If you want to **reset** them to known values, you can use [npm config edit](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-config#edit) or [set](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-config#set):

> `npm config edit`
>
> Opens the config file in an editor. Use the `--global` flag to edit the global config

OR

> `npm config set key=value [key=value...]`
>
> Sets each of the config keys to the value provided.
> If value is omitted, then it sets it to an empty string.

```bash
## e.g. set some proxy configs:
npm config set proxy=example.com https-proxy=example.com ##...
```

Answer (score 0):

config details should be like below

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
strict-ssl=true
http-proxy=null
proxy=null
```

you can make the changes using

```
npm config edit
```